Is there a way to disable Chromium err_internet_disconnected during outage and keep js refresh going until service back up?
This is for a website based image slideshow type app (php/js) I created for large screen TVs at work that we use to advertise upcoming events to our patrons.
The TVs will have mini computers connected via HDMI. The computers startup in Chromium kiosk/fullscreen mode and point to the URL of the app, i.e.,   'https://mysite/tv/hall/index.php'. I use a cached js script to change the images every 10 seconds and location.reload() (a page refresh) after the last image to start a new cycle (allows for changes of new/deleted images).
This all works fine EXCEPT our ATT internet service tends to go down at least once a day. Initially when this occurs, the images stop and I get something to the effect of The content on this page cannot be displayed. If the outage is a short period of time, say less than 2 minutes, the cached js refresh will keep going for a few cycles and if the internet comes back up quickly it goes back to the content. However, anything longer and the refresh stops occurring and Chrome displays an err_internet_disconnected page. The URL does stay the same throughout. I don't have anybody to train to either restart the PC or do an F5 when I am not there, so needs to be automatic.
The current computer is a Raspberry Pi with an earlier edition of Raspberry Pi OS (Linux) using Chromium I had on hand to start out with, however I will use a Windows or Ubuntu based PC on the other TVs with regular Chrome or Chromium ounce I perfect this. I think the issue will still be the same, regardless.
Any ideas of how to either disable this  err_internet_disconnected 'mechanism' in the browser to continue the js page refreshing until the internet comes back up -or- is there a way to set Chromium to refresh itself every hour (since the URL stays the same)? Or restart itself... Or any other ideas?

Lots of potential ways to fix it. Definitely not disabling basic browser "mechanisms" though. This is much more of a coding question that SU material, IMO. I think your way of doing with this is very suboptimal. You could easily switch to doing requests for new images that don't break the page when offline, not to mention cycling properly with JS. Refreshes are completely redundant.
